# Concatenate multiindex

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, multi-index

What's the simplest way to merge 2 dataframes on *both* region and date?

I tried join and merge and concat. I received "'<' not supported between instances of 'float' and 'str' and "cannot handle non-unique multi-index" errors

```
old_df                                  old_value
      region            date      
        England       2010-01-01         4
                      2010-01-02         5
         Wales        2010-01-01         4
                      2010-01-02         3
...
new_df 

                        name         new_value
      region            date      
        England       2010-01-01         10
                      2010-01-02         10
         Wales        2010-01-01         9
                      2010-01-02         10
...
```

Expected Output

```
                                 old_value   new_value 
       region          date      
        England       2010-01-01         4         10
                      2010-01-02         5         10
         Wales        2010-01-01         4         9
                      2010-01-02         3         10
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Works perfectly.  Are you sure you have ensured your date column is a date? `pd.to_datetime()`

```
df_old = pd.read_csv(io.StringIO("""
      region            date      old_value
        England       2010-01-01         4
            nan          2010-01-02         5
         Wales        2010-01-01         4
            nan          2010-01-02         3
"""), sep="\s+")

df_new = pd.read_csv(io.StringIO("""        
      region            date       new_value
        England       2010-01-01         10
            nan          2010-01-02         10
         Wales        2010-01-01         9
             nan         2010-01-02         10"""), sep="\s+")

df_old.region = df_old.region.fillna(method="ffill")
df_new.region = df_new.region.fillna(method="ffill")
df_old.date = pd.to_datetime(df_old.date)
df_new.date = pd.to_datetime(df_new.date)

dfj = df_old.set_index(["region","date"]).join(df_new.set_index(["region","date"]))
```

```
                    old_value  new_value
region  date                            
England 2010-01-01          4         10
        2010-01-02          5         10
Wales   2010-01-01          4          9
        2010-01-02          3         10
```

Comment: Thank you so much. I think it was the datetime. Is there a way to do the same using concat, so I could use the "keys" option in concat?

Comment: I generally use `pd.concat()` to concatenate not join / merge.  this does work: `pd.concat([df_old, df_new], keys=["region","date"], axis=1)`